# the buildozer fails to build apk

Tags: python-3.x

I ran the code on 64-bit Ubuntu 22.04:`buildozer -v android debug`

However, something went wrong.Here is the log:

[heres the log](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1kH6Smw-7WXOu31CQ0qTFJGEbaxujiYVUQ8ZZyUmM7Gg/edit)

I looked for solutions everywhere, but other people's problems didn't exactly match mine.I am in a hurry to solve this problem and hope to get help soon!